# How to show file text in array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, file, methods

Task: Prepare a program that will form a set (array) of letters used in a text file and display it in alphabetical order on the screen.

I want to make Letters(file); (text in file) to show by one letter. But It shows me '*TextFile1.txt'* instead.

*Show* and *Letters* methods are given. My code:

```
static void Main() 
{ 
  string file = "TextFile1.txt"; 
  Show(file); 
  char[] let = Letters(file); 
  foreach (char c in let)
  { 
   Console.WriteLine(c);
  }    
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static void Show(string name)
{
    if (File.Exists(name))
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(name, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("File {0} is not in disc", name);
}
static char[] Letters(string e)
{
    e = e.ToUpper();
    char[] mas = new char[32];
    int n = 0;
    foreach (char r in e)
        if (Array.IndexOf(mas, r) < 0)
            if (Char.IsLetter(r))
                mas[n++] = r;
    Array.Resize(ref mas, n);
    return mas;
}
```

}

Comment: You're passing `file` (i.e. your filename) to `Letters`, instead of the return value of your `ReadAllText` call in `Show`. You're gonna have to return that to your `Main` so you can give that to `Letters`.

Comment: `static char[] Letters(string e) => File.ReadAllText(e).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray();`

Comment: Do you think the assignment allows LINQ, Dmitry? I think it might not be taught yet.. :)

Comment: @bri so, have you been taught `Dictionary<something, somethingelse>` yet?

Comment: @CaiusJard no, last week I just learnt about files

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that makes this particular assignment easier is that C# treats `char` and `int` as equivalent for some contexts and operations; characters have a numerical equivalent - the letter A is 65 in decimal numbers, thanks to historically being located at position 65 in the ASCII table

You can add a character and an integer together; `'A' + 1` is `'B'`, or `66` if youre looking at them numerically. You can subtract one character from another: `'B' - 'A'` is 1

If we are dealing with just a file full of letters, A to Z then that's 26 characters, and they all run sequentially. This sounds like an array, right?

A is 65. Z is 90. This means we actually only need an array that is 91 elements big, to be able to capture any A to Z. 91 is `'Z' + 1`. It doesn't really matter whether you think in numbers or chars for this.

Remember, you have to make an `array[10]` to be able to say `array[0]` to `array[9]`; when you make the array its length is 1 more than the largest index number you will use. To store an array you can index by 'Z' you have to make it `'Z'+1` long:

```
var counts = new int['Z'+1];
```

Now how about doing:

```
counts['A']++; //or could be counts[65], remember that 'A' and 65 are roughly synonymous
```

Counts has now counted 1 'A'

---

So where do you get your chars from to go into the counts?

From the file!

```
foreach(char f in theFileTextAsString){
  counts[f]++;
}
```

Whatever order the chars come in, they increment the correct slot. If the file has ABA, then at the end of this, `counts['A']` is 2, and `counts['B']` is 1

---

Remember that chars can be incremented too, because we can add numbers to them:

```
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++){
    Console.Write(counts[c]);
}
```

That will loop `c` through all the chars in the English alphabet; `c` starts out as `'A'` and then goes to `'B'` and so on, up to/including `'Z'`

---

Have a think about this, and put it all together. Maybe after you've thought about it you can save some memory by having your array run from `'A'-'A'` (i.e. 0) to `'Z'-'A'` (i.e. 25) instead of having it run from `0` to `'Z'`. It would saving a quarter of a kilobyte to get rid of the need to store counts for every char less than 'A' - it wasn't significant enough for me to add confusion to the answer with extraneous math, but once you grok the concept you might want to try adding it in and having a play with chars as numbers etc