# C# String joining adding random numbers

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to append to my string a number and a newline character, but when I do that the number is different and the newline character is gone. MRE below:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "";
        s += 9 + '\n';
        
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        
    }
}
```

Expected output: `9\n`

Actual output: `19`

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering this question because I was lost for a good hour trying to figure out what was causing this.

It comes down to the char `'\n'`. When the line `s += 9 + '\n';` is run, c# interprets the `+` between `9` and `'\n'` as an integer addition, in doing so implicitly converting `'\n'` to it's integer form of `10` (all characters have an integer value, `a` for example is `97`). So what is effectively being run is: `s += 9 + 10;`, which is why the final output is `19`.

If `'\n'` is instead a string: `"\n"`, the code runs as expected and the final result is `9\n`.

So just be careful with `char`s in c#, as they will be converted to integers if possible.

Comment: It's a [very useful thing sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743633/1410664) to be able to treat chars mathematically. `for(char c = 'A'; c<= 'Z'; c++) Console.Write(c);` prints the alphabet, for example

Comment: I understand why the result was confusing. Better options for string concatenation is `string.Format`, interpolated strings or using `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your '\n' to Environment.NewLine, this should work.

Comment: I actually didn't read the expected output lmao my bad, replace '\n' to @"\n"